# How can I merge two instances of one class via Dozer?

Tags: java, dozer

I have class A:

```
public class A {
   String title;
   List<Object> objects;
   //getters, setters
}
```

And two instances of it:

```
A instance1 = new A();
instance1.setTitle("one");
instance1.setObjects(someList1);

A instance2 = new A();
instance2.setTitle("two");
instance2.setObjects(someList2);
```

How can I merge them using BeanDozerMapper so that result would have both titles and full List of Objects?

Comment: Do you want to append properties?

Comment: @AleksandrM you mean dozer config file? Let it be)

Comment: Have you looked at the custom converters? http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html

Comment: Do you want that new title would be `onetwo`?

Comment: @reto, yes, I know, do you suggest me to make converter 
<class-a>com.ex.A</class-a><class-b>com.ex.A</class-b>?

Comment: Yes, this would be an option.

Comment: @AleksandrM, doesn't matters, i want result list contain two lists:
result.addAll(someList1); result.addAll(someList2);

Comment: @reto, and do it via getters and setters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do custom converter to solve it.